# Register CSS file in Sharepoint so that the web part stays themable

Tags: css, sharepoint

I need to register my css file from code behind. Initialy i used the following code:

```
CssRegistration.Register("myStyles.css", true);
```

The problem is, that the file is, like this, expected to be in a folder like 1033/styles within the layout folder. Now there is my problem: For each country (or language region) i need to copy my css into another xxyy/styles-folder. Until now every attempt to solve this situation failed.

**What I tried so far**

Setting a path:

```
CssRegistration.Register("/_layouts/myFolder/myStyles.css", true);
```

This works but if I try to change the theme within Sharepoint, the webpart is not changing anymore.

Using this way:

```
CssRegistration cssRegistration = new CssRegistration 
{ 
  After = "corev4.css", 
  Name = "/_layouts/MyFolder/myStyles.css",
  EnableTheaming = true
}; 
Controls.Add(cssRegistration);
```

Same situation over here...

Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this several times and never had a problem.
First you have to map the Layouts folder in your visual studio project, then insert the CSS over there (but i guess you already did this)

Then you have to do this in your code behind:

```
CssLink cssLink = new CssLink();
cssLink.DefaultUrl="/_layouts/PROJECTNAME/styles/FILE.css";
        if (!this.Page.Header.Controls.Contains(cssLink)) {
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
        }
```

Regards,

Pedro

Mixit.nl

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This is here the same result. The css will be included but it takes always the std. theme of sharepoint and is not changing with the rest.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not changing with the rest"?

Comment: How did you include the .thmx file in visual studio ?

Comment: I didn't include a .thmx file in visual studio. it is not about having an own theme, but creating a web part with the ability to include the colors of the selected theme from the sharepoint itself.